# Getting equation from an unknown curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, interpolation

So, in my problem I have made use of NDSolve to find the solution of the system of differential equations I have. I was wondering if there is a way to get an approximate analytic expression for the solutions, by using the plots of the solutions. Is there a way to fit a curve in an existing one? I know you can do that if you have a data set. One way around this would be to get the dataset of points, out of your curve and then fit a curve in that dataset, but I was wondering if you can do that directly by only using the original curve.

Comment: If memory serves me well back in 2014-2015 [this](https://education.wolfram.com/summer/school/alumni/2012/alessandrini/) was available online

Comment: A specific example would help.

Comment: `NDSolve` produces interpolation functions which work in symbolic expressions just a well as any other function. If you derive an "analytic approximation" the interpolation function using one Mathematica's curve fitting function, you will only make the approximation worse, so I don't see any advantage to what you propose. However, making a data set from the interpolation function with `Table` and then using `FindFormula` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It could be an interesting way to get some insight into the solution when you can't solve it yourself.  Check out the section "Application - Differential Equation" in the reference page for `FindFormula`.